# ellipsoid and paraboloid relation

Tags: computational-geometry

My task was to programme a paraboloid and an ellipsoid. I implemented paraboloid as a set of points that's distance from the focal point and the distance from the plane is the same. After running the compiler, I got something that looked like an ellipsoid.

The mistake was that accidentally I put a multiplier (that was around 1.1) at the distance from focal point. So I got the equation |Q-F|*1.1=|Q-P| , where Q is the point to be decided whether part of the ellipse/paraboloid, F is the focal point, P is point projected from F to the plane(P->F vector is a normalvector of the plane this way). After correcting the equation to |Q-F|=|Q-P|, I got a paraboloid, as expected. When I changed the equation to (|Q-F|*m=|Q-P| ,m>1) I got an ellipsoid. Is this equation really an ellipsoid? I googled a lot but couldnt find the answer.

Any help is appreciated :)